# make context available for template passed to ng-content

Tags: angular

I have 2 module inside app.module.ts namely

1. status.module.ts and
2. table.module.ts

Following is my table component:

```
<ngx-datatable class="material"
           [rows]="rows"
           [columns]="columns"
           [rowClass]="rowClass ? rowClass : null"
           [columnMode]="'force'"
           [headerHeight]="50"
           [footerHeight]="50"
           [rowHeight]="null"
           [limit]="10"
           [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
           [groupRowsBy]="groupRowsBy"
           [groupExpansionDefault]="groupExpansionDefault">

    <!-- Group Header Template -->
    <ngx-datatable-group-header *ngIf="groupRowsBy" >
        <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-group-header>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Now I need to pass the following for ng-content(in table.component.html) from status.component.html:

```
<span>
    <button class="btn btn-link link" (click)="status.openStatus(group)">{{group.key}}</button>
</span>
```

The problem here is that group is not recognized in status.component.html since group is declared in table.component.html

Is there a way I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

in status component, create template reference variable (`appTable`) as:

```
<app-table #appTable>
    <span>
        <button class="btn btn-link link" (click)="status.openStatus(appTable.Group)">{{appTable.Group.key}}</button>
    </span>
</app-table>
```

**table.component** *create setter and getter*

```
_group: any;

set Group(value) {
    this._group = value;
}

get Group() {
    return this._group;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear by your answer. I am getting the value of group variable from let-group="group" which is already inside table.component.

Also, I'm not sure how is the template reference variable being used

Comment: The idea is to access variable of table component in status component. You are using `app-table` in status component so creating a reference of the same in `status` so whenever you call `Group` from `app-table` you get latest value of it and so you will get it in `status`

Comment: aah! now I see what you mean. Just to make my question clear.

ngx-datatable is a 3rd party component and it provides the value for group. I tried using the way you mentioned, it actually creates another property group which is not the same as 3rd party component.

Comment: There must be a way to get value of group from ngx-datatable, you can remove `_group` and return group value from ngx-datatable. Search for it in it's documentation. I guess it's the best possible solution. You can upvote/accept the answer if it helped you anyhow.